# Define NewExpandableDocumentCommand whose name is in a macro

Tags: latex3, xparse

If a macro or an argument (say `#1`) contains some strings, say `Mystring`, I can create a macro `\PrefixMystring{}{}` using something like:

```
\expandafter\newcommand\csname Prefix#1\endcsname[2]{
  the arguments are ##1 and ##2
}
```

I'd like to do something similar with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`, what is the proper way to proceed?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

%% \createNewAnimal{Cat}{Miaou} should create a new command \helloCat{Bob} outputting "Miaou Bob".
\NewDocumentCommand{\createNewAnimal}{mm}{
  %%% How can I do the same with NewExpandableDocumentCommand instead of newcommand?
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname hello#1\endcsname[1]{
    #2 ##1.
  }
}

\createNewAnimal{Cat}{Miaou}
\createNewAnimal{Dog}{Woooof}

\helloCat{Bob}
\helloDog{Alice}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
Oh in fact, in my tests the above method was failing with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`… but the reason is that I was adding braces around the arguments, like: `\expandafter\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\csname zx#2\endcsname}{}{…}` instead of `\expandafter\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\csname zx#2\endcsname{}{…}`, which was giving an error:

```
ERROR: LaTeX cmd Error: First argument of '\NewExpandableDocumentCommand' must be a command
```

Problem solved with:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

%% \createNewAnimal{Cat}{Miaou} should create a new command \helloCat{Bob} outputting "Miaou Bob".
\NewDocumentCommand{\createNewAnimal}{mm}{
  %%% How can I do the same with NewExpandableDocumentCommand instead of newcommand?
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname hello#1\endcsname{m}{
    #2 ##1.
  }
}

\createNewAnimal{Cat}{Miaou}
\createNewAnimal{Dog}{Woooof}

\helloCat{Bob}
\helloDog{Alice}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try to apply  your method?

Comment: but \ExpandArgs (which does the same under the hood) looks nicer and is less typing.

Comment: Actually I was confused: the reason is that I needed to remove the brace around the csname, see my edit.

Comment: it isn't clear what you are asking here, any method you use for `\newcommand` you could use for `\NewDocumentCommand` `\csname` as in your question, or `\ExpandArgs` as in the posted answer are general mechanisms.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The reason I asked this question was because I thought csname was not working for `\NewDocumentCommand` because when I tested it it was failing as I forgot to remove the brakets around csname. So problem solved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `\ExpandArgs` is a possibility for this (I don't know if there are better alternatives, though).

```tex
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

%% \createNewAnimal{Cat}{Miaou} should create a new command \helloCat{Bob} outputting "Miaou Bob".
\NewDocumentCommand{\createNewAnimal}{mm}{%
  \ExpandArgs{c}\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{hello#1}{m}{#2 ##1.}%
}

\createNewAnimal{Cat}{Miaou}
\createNewAnimal{Dog}{Woooof}

\helloCat{Bob}
\helloDog{Alice}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually I realized that I could use `\expandafter`, see my edit, but this method is interesting as well. Any idea how it compares to expandafter? I guess it also work better on multiple arguments? I can see also the `N` keyword when one argument should not be expanded.

Comment: @tobiasBora Yes, in hindsight I guess you could have used `\expandafter`, I just assumed you had tried and it hadn't worked. As Ulrike says in a comment, it does the same thing under the hood. But the syntax of `\ExpandArgs` is more convenient, specially if more arguments are involved. And, yes, the same expansion possibilities for the arguments are available as those for `expl3`'s `\exp_args:`, but truth is I don't know where `\ExpandArgs` is documented.

Comment: @gusbrs `texdoc usrguide`, section 4

Comment: @egreg Thanks, good to know. I tend to still use `texdoc xparse`, so that's where the up to date stuff is going. Is the `clsguide` also receiving equivalent updates?

Comment: @gusbrs yes (slowly:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good news, I'll put those back in my texdoc list.  :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Quick practical question, if I may. Do you know if `texdoc usrguide` currently already encompass the full contents of `texdoc xparse`? (I might just set a texdoc alias, if that's the case, to help me get rid of the old habit).

Comment: @gusbrs I think so (Joseph's doing it mostly) apart from bits of xparse like `g` that we didn't copy to `ltcmd`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Great, thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest a generic macro factory.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewPrefixedDocumentCommand}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = prefix
  % #2 = added part
  % #3 = argument list
  % #4 = replacement text
  \tobiasbora_prefixed:Nnnnn \NewDocumentCommand { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewPrefixedExpandableDocumentCommand}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = prefix
  % #2 = added part
  % #3 = argument list
  % #4 = replacement text
  \tobiasbora_prefixed:Nnnnn \NewExpandableDocumentCommand { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tobiasbora_prefixed:Nnnnn
 {
  \exp_args:Nc #1 { #2 #3 } { #4 } { #5 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% test for the generic function
\NewPrefixedDocumentCommand{Prefix}{Test}{mm}{Do something with #1 and #2}

% test for your use case
\NewDocumentCommand{\createNewAnimal}{mm}{%
  \NewPrefixedDocumentCommand{hello}{#1}{m}{#2 ##1.}%
}

\createNewAnimal{Cat}{Miaou}
\createNewAnimal{Dog}{Woooof}

\begin{document}

\PrefixTest{A}{B}

\helloCat{Bob}
\helloDog{Alice}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In these particular cases you might also use `\NewPrefixedExpandableDocumentCommand`, but be careful: using `Expandable` does not apply some kind of magic that makes expandable what isn't such.

Answer (score 4):

You can use simply TeX primitives in order to solve your "animal problem":

```
\def\createNewAnimal#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname hello#1\endcsname##1{#2 ##1}}

\createNewAnimal{Cat}{Miaou}
\createNewAnimal{Dog}{Woooof}

\helloCat{Bob}    % prints: Miaou Bob

\helloDog{Alice}  % prints: Woooof Alice
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to use LaTeX3 syntax for simpler handling of complex arguments (in real like I'm interested by more complex use-cases than cat and dogs ^^).

Comment: @tobiasBora The `\def` primitive enables the most complex arguments. In fact, the `\NewDocumentCommad` is based on the `\def` primitive.

Comment: Oh sure, but I guess this liberty has downsides. Like as a user I find the `\NewDocumentCommand` much more practical to define optional arguments, or star versions of a command, or check the presence of tokens… For instance the current function I'm using is defined with `t.t-t'O{}O{default stuff}m`… with `\def` I don't even know how I could do that…